# How do I record one specific application audio?

Tags: audio, recording

Basically what is happening right now is I 'm running a Shure SM7b through an GoXLR mixing table that let me put discord for example on of the mixer called Voice Chat, and my video game are going through System, I want to know if there is a application that let me record all these guy and let me separate the lane in Premiere Pro, so for example if one my friend said something and i want to be able to separate in the editing part so we can only hear his voice and not the game with it.

Sorry if this is a lot but I really want to know if it possible.

Comment: seems [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJEKDL_cN2U) (among many similar) does what you want - though, they use OBS to do some of the majicks